# Determine the coefficients such that the function is continious

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
x^2-\alpha x+\beta,& \text{for } x< -1\\(\alpha +\beta)x,& \text{for }-1<x<1, \\x^2+\alpha x-\beta, & \text{for }x >1\end{cases}$$

Determine the values for $\alpha, \beta$ such that the function is continuous on $\Bbb R$

For $f$ to be continuous, i need to show that for each case the function has a real limit. and for example, for the first case $x^2-\alpha x+\beta$, as limit goes to $-1$ we have $1+\alpha+\beta$...If i continue on like this i should get enough equations and in the end just solve the system of equations to get the values for $\alpha, \beta$. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The given function is continuous for all values of $\alpha,\beta$. Did you mean equality at the end points $-1,1$?

Comment: Evaluate $(x^2-\alpha x + \beta) = (\alpha+\beta)x$ when $x=-1$ which is one of the joints. $1+\alpha+\beta = -\alpha -\beta$. so $\alpha + \beta = -\frac{1}{2}$. And similarly for $x=1$., which is the other joint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find values of $\alpha,\beta$ that make $f$ continuous first observe that, as vidyarthi pointed out, all of the piecewise components are continuous themselves, on their respective intervals. Letting
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
f_1(x),&x<-1 \\
f_2(x),&-1<x<1 \\
f_3(x),&x>1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We can then see that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^-}f_1(x)=f_1(-1)$, etc... . Visualizing the graph of the function we have three seperate piecewise components which need to 'line up'. Hence according to the above comments we need $\alpha,\beta$ to be such that $f_1(-1)=f_2(-1)$ as well as $f_2(1)=f_3(1)$.

Also it should be noted that $f$, as given, is not defined on $-1$ or $1$ meaning you must either adjust the inequalities or define the function on these values explicitly.